# Angular 5 Reactive Forms - Issues setting date returned from DB

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I've got a reactive form within angular 5 where I edit some data. To edit the data I of-course first pull the data from the DB and display it within my reactive form.

**The DB returns the date is the following format:**

```
2017-07-13T23:00:00.000Z
```

**My HTML code is:**

```
 <input class="uk-input" type="date" placeholder="Enter Issue Date" formControlName="IssueDate">
```

**My Component Code is:**

```
this.proposalForm.setValue({

      sector: this.proposal.sector,
      client: this.proposal.client,
      owner: this.proposal.owner,
      IssueDate: this.proposal.IssueDate,

  });
```

**All the text fields are populated but the `date` field remains empty. What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Input [`type="date"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) supports YYYY-MM-DD  format only. 
You can do `this.proposal.IssueDate.substr(0,10)` or `this.proposal.IssueDate.split('T')[0]`

```js
var somedate = "2017-07-13T23:00:00.000Z";

my_date.value = somedate.substr(0,10);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="my_date"/>
```